# What is the Time Complexity of System.out.println?

Tags: java, time-complexity, big-o

Suppose code like this:

```
String[] arr = {"Cat", "Dog", "Maple", "Blue"};

for (String str : arr) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Would the time complexity be O(N) in this case or O(N^2)?

At the first glance, it seems O(N) but I thought about it and since str is not constant, It's O(N^2) in this case?

Comment: It's O(N) if N is the total lengths of all the strings in the array, or equivalently O(nk) if n is the length of the array and k is the average length of the strings.

Comment: If N means the length of your array, then it's O(N). It would only be N squared if the length of the strings was proportional to the length of the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time complexity for the `for` loop will be `O(n)` where `n` is the size of the array.

The `System.out.println()` take `O(k)` time to print `k` characters the average time complexity of the above piece of code should be `O(nk)`;

The `System.out.println` internally uses the following code:

```
public void write(String str, int off, int len) throws IOException {
    synchronized (lock) {
        char cbuf[];
        if (len <= WRITE_BUFFER_SIZE) {
            if (writeBuffer == null) {
                writeBuffer = new char[WRITE_BUFFER_SIZE];
            }
            cbuf = writeBuffer;
        } else {    // Don't permanently allocate very large buffers.
            cbuf = new char[len];
        }
        str.getChars(off, (off + len), cbuf, 0);
        write(cbuf, 0, len);
    }
}
```

Comment: System.out.println itself will have a constant O(1) worst case complexity.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri No man, it takes `O(k)`. Look at the code I posted.

Comment: No algorithm can possibly print an output of arbitrary size in O(1) time.

Comment: @PritamBanerjee and k is the length of the String? ok, sure :) but just a granularity of estimation will be way higher. Maybe I just looked on that from a bit higher abstraction :) so, if it would go into n^2 look, I would definitely answer on interview, that the algorithm's O is n^2.. not n^2*k. :) rounding to the higher degree operation (please correct me if I'm wrong, would appreciate that :))

Comment: @kaya3 yeah, sorry, expressed myself in a bit higher level :) Sure, printing 2 chars and printing one book will take different times. What I meant is that having prinln in n^2 loop, will most likely be answered that the complexity of O is n^2. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri If by an n^2 loop you mean a loop which iterates O(n^2) times, then you still need to multiply that by the complexity of whatever the loop does on each iteration.

Comment: That's true, @kaya3, sure. For example n(log(n)).. but if you have the algorithm of loop, inside the loop, where you just print the character.. what's the complexity of that algorithm you would say?

Comment: If you print one character then that takes O(1) time, of course.